# Is it possible to use Xcode for Linux Development?

Tags: c++, linux, xcode, macos, ide

My team is planning to start development on linux platform. Previously we have been developing C++ applications in Windows using MS Visual Studio. And recently, I fell in love with Mac OSX and use it as my personal development machine.

The question is once again: Is it possible to use Xcode for Linux Development?

The applications we are building are real-time applications, which do not require fancy looking GUIs or advanced user interaction, the focus is on the performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you stick to cross-platform interfaces (glibc, POSIX, STL, etc.), sure. You *might* need a Linux machine to actually build the binaries for Linux though.

Comment: ... or set up a cross-compile environment to compile for Linux. I've cross-compiled on Linux for other Linux platforms (different CPUs) and from my experience I don't see a reason why it should not be possible to cross-compile on Mac OS X to Linux. Hard, but possible. [Dan Kegel's crosstool](http://www.kegel.com/crosstool/) might be of help for that.

Comment: if we do on cross-compile environment, can we still do debugging using xcode?

Comment: gdb is capable of remote debugging, but I'm not sure if Xcode exposes that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible since both xcode and linux are using gcc and could use similar development toolkits, and both osx and linux are unix based, therefore you can debug and code on osx, but I think you still need to recompile your apps on deployment O/S ( so make sure you're using portable codes between osx and linux)